# Which ARIA role to use "main" or "feed"?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

I'm trying to improve the accessibility of a web app that is mostly used for reading RSS. It has a lot of complex functionalities and is written quite some time ago (doesn't use HTML5). I don't want to change anything about its layout and markup, I only want to specify the appropriate roles of the elements. I have a single container that holds articles coming from the RSS feed, so it sounds perfect to use the "feed" role. However, that's also the main content section. I can't wrap it in another parent container. So which role is best to use - "main" or "feed"?

EDIT: Articles load dynamically. Also if I use the 'feed' role I will have no 'main' one (there's also no  tag in the markup).

The markup is similar to this:

```
<div role="main/feed">
<div role="article"></div>
<div role="article"></div>
<div role="article"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are these articles adding up dynamically or the content is fixed?

Comment: The content is dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Per [the mozilla description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/Feed_Role) for `feed`:

> A feed is a dynamic scrollable list of articles in which articles are added to or removed from either end of the list as the user scrolls.

Based on dynamic content, `feed` is probably your best bet.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought too, but I wanted to be sure. So I guess it's not a problem if the "main" role is missing?

Comment: I wouldn't think this would pose an issue for an accessible reader- your 'main' role is usually assigned using a `<main>` which would wrap both your articles and any other descriptive features

Comment: just nest your feed somewhere inside main. This is a completely acceptable arrangement.